# Python - decimal to integer low byte then high byte

Tags: python, integer, hex, byte, decimal

Hello I'm a newbie with Python but I've been interested on it for 2 years. I want to make robots and I'm trying to use Python with `pyserial` on blender. But I found a problem and after 2 hours of looking for the answer in Google  and in this site I found that maybe I'm retarded because I can't solve it. I think it isn't asked yet.

I'm using a devantech sd84 servo controller and controling it via a USB port a serial device so I use `pyserial`. The problem is that I want Python to take a decimal value fom a user input between `400`-`2200` and I know how to do it but I need Python to show it as two bytes and send the low byte first and then the high byte. for example *(pseudo code as I don't how to program it yet)*:

```
    #ask for a decimal number between a range (the range does not really matters)
    x = raw_input('\tInsert a number between 400-2200:') #Insert a number between 400-2200: 1500
    #show it as hex
    hex(x) #5dc
    #put it in two bytes and in this case add a zero(?) I don't know how to do that.
    0xDC 0x05
    #add it to a 16-bit integer to send it to the servo controller via the virtual serial port(?) i also don't know how to do that. 
   ser.write('\xAA\xA0\x55\x01\x01\x02\xDC\x05')
```

For the interest of people who have the same controler I'll explane that 16bit integer first three bytes are sync `(\xAA\xA0\x55)` then the type of command SET_SERVO (position) (\x01) then the channel 1-84 for 1 is (\x01) then a byte count in this case 2 (\x02) and the servo position low byte and then the high byte (\xDC\x05) which nowadays I calculate with in my iPod with an app and then I insert manually hahaha I want to stop whith that stupid thing and let he compuer do it for me.

Now I will post a code I made for testing purposes it mades a servo in channel 1 go troug it's full range ata different speeds and print funny things in spanish while the servo "dances" I manually calculated the positons and inserted them hahaha sounds like history for me.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #Pablo P. 2012 "bailecillo"
    #mueve un servo en el canal 1 a través de todo su recorido e imprime frases mientras dicho servo "baila"
    import serial
    import time
    # Para cambiar de Sistema Operativo cambiar puerto 
    #en la siguiente línea: Win COM# linux /dev/ttyS# /dev/ttyUSB#
    # #=un número asignado por tu sistema.
    port='COM3'
    sync='\xAA\xA0\x55'
    SET_SERVO='\x01'
    GET_SERVO='\x02'
    SET_SPEED='\x03'
    SET_MODE='\x04'
    GET_MODE='\x05'
    SET_AD_CNT='\x06' #Controla el número de canales analógicos.
    GET_AD_CNT='\x07' #Devuelve el número de canales analógicos actuales.
    GET_INPUT='\X08' # Devuelve el estado de una entrada.
    GET_ADC='\X09' #Devuelve el valor de un canal analógico.
    GET_VERSION='\x0A' #Devuelve la versión del procesador seleccionado.
    GET_BULK='\x15' #Usado para test en fábriica.
    TEST='\X16' #Usado para test en fábrica.
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=2,timeout=1)

   print "Hola! me alegro de verte."
   time.sleep(2)

   if ser.isOpen():
print "Estado del puerto: Correcto."
time.sleep(1)
print "Procedo a enviar modo del canal 1 y posicion(es) del mismo."
time.sleep(3)
print "Comprobando sistemas de baile..."
ser.write(sync+SET_MODE+'\x01\x01\x19')
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x98\x08') #izda
time.sleep(3)
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x90\x01') #derecha
time.sleep(1)
ser.write(sync+SET_SPEED+'\x01\x01\x10')
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x78\x05') #centro
time.sleep(2)
print "Vamos a bailar!"
time.sleep(2)
print "preparados..."
time.sleep(1)
print "listos..."
time.sleep(1)
print "Yaaaa!!"
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x98\x08') #izda
time.sleep(3)
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x90\x01') #derecha
time.sleep(3)
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x98\x08') #izda
time.sleep(3)
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x90\x01') #derecha
time.sleep(3)
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x98\x08') #izda
time.sleep(3)
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x90\x01') #derecha
time.sleep(3)
ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02\x78\x05') #centro
time.sleep(3)
ser.write(sync+SET_SPEED+'\x01\x01\x00')
ser.close()
time.sleep(1)
print "Todo el proceso completado correctamente."

    else:
        print "El puertito está cerrado"

    print "Hasta Luego :D"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is why programmers new to Python should look over the [libref](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html).

```
>>> struct.pack('<h', 1500)
'\xdc\x05'
```

Comment: okay i'll try to read it, but it doesn't works for me: Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:12:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> struct.pack('<h', 1500)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    struct.pack('<h', 1500)
NameError: name 'struct' is not defined

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> struct.pack('<h', 1500)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    struct.pack('<h', 1500)
NameError: name 'struct' is not defined

Comment: `struct` is a module in the stdlib that you must [import](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import struct
print struct.pack('<h', 1500)
>>> 
Ü

Comment: why it returns those ascii characters?

Comment: when i try to read bytes from the servo controller it also returns ascii characters why python show those bytes as ascii characters?

Comment: Characters have byte representations too. Guess which byte representations *those* characters have?

Comment: @Pablo: ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: okay i've read the whole thing and i've learned the characters are not necessari ascii but possibly utf-8. is there a way for python to show them as bytes without the encoding?

Comment: Encoding them with the `hex` codec will convert them to nibbles as text. `>>> 'abc'.encode('hex')`
`'616263'`

Comment: i think i get it no matter what it shows me as it understand the bytes so if i introduce the result in my 16-bit inger it would run, isn't it?

Comment: ok i found the problem, i was using the print() command and not using de IDLE hahaha so print() encodes the result by default hahaha i can't pay your help today thank you very much you saved me :)

Comment: now i have another problem sorry you don't have to answer if you don't want to: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pablo/Desktop/te pide un numero", line 28, in <module>
    POS_SERVO = struct.pack('<h', 'posicion')
error: cannot convert argument to integer` how can i say it's not an argument but a decimal value?

Comment: @Pablo: If you have another question then you should open another question.

Comment: `posicion = raw_input('\tInserta un numero entre 400 y 2200:')
 POS_SERVO = struct.pack('<h', 'posicion')
 ser.write(sync+SET_MODE+'\x01\x01\x19')
 ser.write(sync+SET_SERVO+'\x01\x02'+POS_SERVO)`

Answer (score 0):

This should create a hex string corresponding to the input integer x

```
hex_list = ['%02X' % int((hex(int(hex(x)[2:],16) >> i & 0xff)[2:]),16) for i in (0,8)]

string = ''
for element in hex_list:
    string = string + '\\x' + element

string.decode('string_escape')
```

or

```
hex_list = ''.join(["\\x" + ('%02X' % int((hex(int(hex(x)[2:],16) >> i & 0xff)[2:]),16) )  for i in (0,8)]).decode('string_escape')
```

Comment: it's interesting but i want low.high because the servo controler integer requires it. thank you very much.

Comment: The `write()` method of a pysSerial.Serial object sends a `str` or `bytearray`  to the port. The OP has indicated that they want the integer x value in low byte, high byte order -- however your expression builds a `list` of bytes in the wrong order.

Comment: x = 1500
print[hex(int(hex(x)[2:],16) >> i & 0xff) for i in (0,8)]

Comment: >>> 
['0xdc', '0x5'] its okay but i don't know how to insert that on the 16-bit integer which i send troug the port

Comment: Ü| it returns pretty the same as the other answer and the other solution looks simply. but I still have the problem with these characters because i want bytes. how can i reach that because i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: okay thank you very much you also solved my problem in a different way without using any module. that was great :)

Comment: Definitely messier than the struct, but without the module